# What does “dittatura legalizzata” mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

What does the phrase “dittatura legalizzata” mean in this context?

[image: Image of quote about government and law, mentioning the phrase “dittatura legalizzata”.]

Trascrizione:

> Si discusse in dottrina se effettivamente con la legge del 1939 fosse venuta meno la precedente generica competenza del Governo a emettere decreti-legge in casi di urgente necessità, ovvero se la medesima sussistesse ancora in base al non abrogato art. 3 n. 2 della Lg. 1926 o in base alla necessità intesa come fonte di produzione giuridica, ma di fatto la decretazione governativa continuò a essere l’ordinario strumento di legiferazione, trasformandosi in un’orgia che attingeva al ridicolo e ignorava il più elementare buon senso, in un regime che chiamava le Camere soltanto « a collaborare con il Governo » nella formazione delle leggi, mentre precipitavano gli eventi che dovevano portare alla catastrofe militare e al crollo della **dittatura legalizzata**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "legalized dictatorship".
Fascism could be considered a "legalized dictatorship" because it basically acted like a dictatorship without formally breaking the laws of the time.
For instance, as described in this article, they used "decreto legge" - which was meant as an "exceptional" tool to pass urgent laws quickly and with less opposition - as their standard way to pass laws.